# HTML file wont open on browser when double clicked (drag and drop the file on a browser works)

Tags: html, windows, browser

This is a pretty weird problem. Not sure if this question is acceptable.

Every time i open an HTML file by double clicking it or opening it using a browser the browser home page appears not the HTML file. I've tried using different browser but all have the same results. If i try to drag and drop the HTML file in the browser it works. If I also type the file path in the URL it also works. Not sure why directly opening the HTML cause this kind of problem.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: In browser settings, how is it set to start? (Are you on windows and installed some package with some "bar"?)

Comment: also, does it happen on all browsers or just one?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall he said, *"I've tried using different browser but all have the same results."*

Comment: @cox what do you mean by windows? No browser is open.

Answer (score 1):

Try restoring your browser settings.

Here are some links to help you with resetting the settings:

1. Reset settings in [chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en).
2. Reset settings in [internet explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737).
3. Reset settings in [opera](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/10081-reset-opera-to-default-settings).
4. Reset settings in [firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).

Answer (score 0):

same problem on a particular  windows 7 system with the 3 browser I installed (Chrome, IE11 FireFox)

Reseting programs default association file with control panel or trying manual "registry tricks" doesn't solve the issue.

Any of the 3 browser still opens on their default start page, ignoring .html file the user double-clicked.

3 "work-arround" I found :
1- open the browser
2- Ctrl+O to open file with a dialog("where on hell did they put the menu bar?)

1- open the browser
2- drag'n drop the html file

1- rigth-click on html file inside explorer
2- "open with"
3- "select an other program" (mandatory step, if you try pre-selected programs, it won't works)
4- select your browser

=> I think the problem resid in the intermediate layer component(s) wired in windows root registry keys that handle html file extensions. I suspect those component(s) to strip the "%1" param of browser launch command line, but I have no time and no will to investigate such a poor Windows issue